# I want to compile a figure or a graph, and I couldn´t

Tags: miktex, texify

I use the package `graphicx`;
and I couldn´t compile, appear the text:

> this application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin.
>
> Reinstalling the application.

I used TeXWorks and TeXMaker, and this is the complete error message:

> Sorry, but "C:\Users\Trabajo\Desktop\M ikteX\miktex\bin\texify.exe"
>   did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to
>   get MiKTeX going again:
>   C:/Users/Trabajo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log You
>   may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Comment: That's not a compilation error. It has nothing to do with TeX. It might be connected with your editor or your viewer.